# Unable to append rows to postgresql table using pd.to_sql while omitting the primary key

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Apologies for what I assume is a basic question, I am new to this. I am running into an issue while appending rows to a `Postgresql` table in `pandas` and hosed on Amazon RDS. I created an empty table called `try` with 4 fields, with `record_id` as a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, using the following statement:

```
("""CREATE TABLE try(
record_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
symbol text,
name float,
start_popularity integer)""")
```

Pulling the table using:

```
df1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM try', con)
```

yields an empty table with the expected structure:

```
record_id   symbol  name    start_popularity
```

I am attempting to append 5 rows from a dataframe called `df_try` to the table and omitting record_ID since I want the database to assign a a primary key automatically (it is posting fine when I generate record_id and append the entire dataframe).

```
    symbol  name    start_popularity
0   A   Agilent 1480
1   AA  Alcoa   5733
2   AACG    ATA Creativity Global   1663
3   AAL American Airlines   659935
4   AAN Aarons  103
```

I am using the following approach:

```
df_try.to_sql('try', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I am getting a DataError:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "Agilent"
LINE 1: ...try (symbol, name, start_popularity) VALUES ('A', 'Agilent',...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add your PostgreSQL table definition with datatypes for each column.

Comment: Further to comment from @Mike - The error message indicates that you are trying to insert the string 'Agilent' into a column of type `double`. That obviously won't work.

Comment: looks like I had name set as a float rather than text. Thank you i totally missed it